# Chamar função javascript de dentro de um bloco ASP Clássico

Tags: javascript, asp

Como eu faço para executar uma função javascript de dentro de um bloco asp clássico. A função js não está no mesmo arquivo, está fora, em outro arquivo.

```
<%
if(MINHA_FUNÇÂO_JS_AQUI)
response.write "<img align='middle' width='24' height='24' name='img_negociacao_local_internacao' id='img_negociacao_local_internacao' src='onClick='javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();' >&nbsp;"
%>
```

Comment: Eu fiz um comentário no meta, sobre downvote e estou recebendo downvotes sem mesmo merecer, ou seja, por puro ódio, mas ainda vou continuar com a minha opinião a respeito desses caras aqui. Estão escondidos, uns covardes.

Comment: Certamente é um problema do StackOverFlow. Tem o link do tópico, quero acompanhar!

Comment: Acho que os votos negativos dessa pergunta estão vindo por causa de não possuir nenhum código ou exemplificação do que deseja (O que acho que não seja um motivo para dar voto negativo). E sim, é mesmo um problema...

Comment: Pô, mas pense comigo. É uma pergunta bem genérica, não vejo o porque ter um código. Como eu disse, eu tenho uma página asp e preciso chamar uma função js, mas vou pegar uma das muitas vezes que isso vai acontecer, vou blocar o código.

Comment: Isto não é possível.

Comment: Não foi eu que negativei. Mas concordo com você. Vota negativo, não fala o porquê e ninguém edita.

Comment: A própria plataforma da um "lembrete" para considerar um comentário ao negativar. É comum eu ver alguns downvotes e nenhum comentário. Chego a pensar se para a nossa realidade não seria necessário obrigar um comentário para usar o downvote, infelizmente.

Comment: up vote, pergunta clara e objetiva, é que está na moda dar downvote..rs

Answer (score 1):

**Não é possível.**

`ASP Classic` é interpretado pelo servidor e enviado o html já processado para o client. 
`Javascript` é processado apenas no client.

**Seria possível fazer o contrário javascript chamar ou receber variável asp**, ex

```
alert('<%=variavel%>');
```

pois na verdade quando o processamento ocorre primeiro no server iria retornar para o client

```
alert('valor_da_variavel');
```

Então, infelizmente não é possível você fazer isso mesmo programando ASP Classic com vbscript ou javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, utilize duas vezes as aspas """" desta forma o ASP irá interpretar normalmente, caso utilize apóstrofo ' o ASP entende que é um comentário.

no seu código de exemplo verifiquei que o src="" estava incorreto.

segue abaixo a maneira de inserir código javascript no ASP em uma variável:

```
<%
response.write "<img align=""middle"" width=""24"" height=""24"" name=""img_negociacao_local_internacao"" id=""img_negociacao_local_internacao"" src=""digite o endereço da imagem"" onClick=""javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();"" >&nbsp;"
%>
```

Esta é a saída:

```
<html><body>
<img align="middle" width="24" height="24" name="img_negociacao_local_internacao" id="img_negociacao_local_internacao" src="" onclick="javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();">&nbsp;
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Não é possível** você colocar o `JS` **diretamente ligado** ao `ASP` então esqueça utilizá-lo como **parte da lógica** pois a forma como o `ASP` e o `JS` são processadas é diferente, ou seja, se você tentar colocar sua função `JS` como condição para um laço de repetição ou mesmo em uma condicional simples(`IF`) ele não funcionará pois o `ASP` é interpretado pelo **servidor** e só depois no lado do **cliente** o `JS` será processado.

**Porém é possível** que você inclua a chamada a uma função `JS` **dentro de um elemento `HTML`**, desde que você tenha o script com função no documento seja ele um `JS` externo incluído ou não.

Então fora o `if(MINHA_FUNÇÂO_JS_AQUI)` que **definitivamente não funcionará**
um outro problema no seu código é que você concatenou o trecho de `JS` no elemento `HTML` de forma errada:

```
<%= "<img src='onClick='javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();' />" %>
```

o correto seria:

```
<%= "<img onClick='javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();' />" %>
```

Ou

```
<%= "<img onClick=""javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();"" />" %>
```

Esse código será interpretado pelo servidor e criará o seguinte `HTML`:

```
<img onclick="javascript:abrirNegociacaoTipoAtendimento();" />
```